# ionic Hardware back not working after displaying ads

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

**Ionic version:** 
 **3.x**

**Current behavior:**
After registering the hardware back then if ads are displayed, pressing the hardware back exits the app and does not bind to the normal behavior

**Expected behavior:**
Hardware back should execute the registered functions

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Create a new app with any template add.
2. Add the admob-free plugin
3. Register hardwarback to log something(Not to exit).
4. Display ads.
5. Press hardware back

**Related code:**

**In the constructor of app.component.ts** register the back handler

```
    platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
    console.log("Back Pressed");
  });
```

Display banner ads or interstitials then without pressing anything in the app press the back button.
The app will exit. We are not exiting the app in our handler.

APP REPO [HERE](https://github.com/prantikv/ionicAdsBack).

A related issue can be seen [here.](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro/issues/161)

**Ionic Info:**

```
cli packages: (C:\Users\prantikv\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.12.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.12.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.0.1

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.0
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.0.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.7.1

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 25.2.5
    Node              : v6.11.3
    npm               : 5.4.2
    OS                : Windows 10

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

Comment: the solution provided in the reference didnot solved your issue?

Comment: Not for me. Also, that is something that requires editing of the cordova files. Which is not a permanent solution on the developer side.

Comment: its not editing in cordova files , its making custom plugin for your own application , and its safe to use, i have modified some plugin to fit my need.

Comment: The solution provided is for another admob plugin. I have referenced it because there is the same issue with the plugin currently being used by me, which is the admob-free plugin. I tried the solution and it did not work for me, maybe because the solution is tailored to that plugin and not to the one I am using.  Can suggest any changes. I am ok with changes to the plugin  files if need be

Answer (score 1):

Add your addeventlistener to the document, and capture the event in the capture phase. It will be useful to `stopPropagation` when the event is fired, to prevent other event listeners from firing.

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, true);
```